# Customize the output on the browser print

Tags: html, css, browser, printing

I'm trying to move certain elements when a print (or print preview) occurs from the browser.

Originally HTML looks like this

```
<li>
    <ul id="Remarks" class="Remarks">
       <li class="Header  soldBKG">Showing Information</li>
       <li><p><b>Remarks:</b></p></li>
      <li class="btmRow">
         <ul class="btmRow">
            <li><span>Occupant Name</span><span class="data">Listing Office</span></li>
            <li><span>Occupancy/Show</span><span class="data">Listing Agent</span></li>
            <li><span>Occupant Type</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
            <li><span>Occupant Phone</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
            <li><span>Other Phone Number</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
         </ul>
       </li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="btmRow MarginFix" id="btmRowMarginFix">
        <li></li>
        <li><span>Phone To Show</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
        <li><span>LockBox Location</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
        <li><span>LockBox Type</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
        <li><span>Showing Access</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

After changes my HTML should like this :

```
<li>
    <ul id="Remarks" class="Remarks">
       <li class="Header  soldBKG">Showing Information</li>
       <li><p><b>Remarks:</b></p></li>
       <li class="btmRow">
         <ul class="btmRow">
            <li><span>Occupant Name</span><span class="data">Listing Office</span></li>
            <li><span>Occupancy/Show</span><span class="data">Listing Agent</span></li>
            <li><span>Occupant Type</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
            <li><span>Occupant Phone</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
            <li><span>Other Phone Number</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
         </ul>

         <ul class="btmRow MarginFix" id="btmRowMarginFix">
            <li></li>
            <li><span>Phone To Show</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
            <li><span>LockBox Location</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
            <li><span>LockBox Type</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
            <li><span>Showing Access</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>

  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a plugin that might work for you:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-edit/

Comment: I think this only works on FF but I want this change on all the browsers